# Document text extraction and modification

Tags: java

I recently came across [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org), a beautiful toolkit which handles files of several types to extract the text (and some other information such as metadata).

The problem which I am facing is that given a document (in some format such as PDF, DOC, XLS and so on), I need to **extract** the text, **modify** some of it, and **re-build** the document in its original format (with the modified text). To my knowledge, Tika provides the facility of extraction of text, but does not 'stitch' modified documents back.

I feel that there are some libraries which do this for **specific** file types, but I am not aware of any toolkit similar to Tika, which provides an end-to-end solution for me by handling **all** the file types supported by Tika. I am also not sure if Tika itself can do this for me.

If someone knows anything of this sort, please let me know. I am looking for a library written in Java.

Regards,

Salil

EDIT:  coderanch.com/how-to/java/AccessingFileFormats has several toolkits lister, but I would appreciate something that wraps all the formats supported by Tika comprehensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Apache POI

Apache POI is your Java Excel solution (for Excel 97-2008). We have a complete API for porting other OOXML and OLE2 formats and welcome others to participate.

OLE2 files include most Microsoft Office files such as XLS, DOC, and PPT as well as MFC serialization API based file formats. The project provides APIs for the OLE2 Filesystem (POIFS) and OLE2 Document Properties (HPSF).

Office OpenXML Format is the new standards based XML file format found in Microsoft Office 2007 and 2008. This includes XLSX, DOCX and PPTX.

- Eclipse Birt

  Q: What report output formats does BIRT support?

Release 2.1 supports HTML, Paginated HTML and PDF.
Release 2.2 support HTML, Paginated HTML, PDF, WORD, XLS, and PostScript

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for something which supports PDF, XML, PPT and other Office formats comprehensively. 

This link has more details: https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/AccessingFileFormats

But all these (and the ones which you mentioned) have some format or other missing. I am looking for something which wraps all these formats (similar to Tika).

Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are no better toolkits as mentioned [here](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/AccessingFileFormats). The only way out would be to write your own wrapper for one or more of these toolkits to get the work done. It would have been great if Tika itself provided that facility, but that unfortunately does not seem to be the case.